# Sending variables inside a response node.js, vainilla js

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to learn nodejs and vainillajs for web development, making my first project after some months of tutorials, and im in having some very basic doubts, dont know if im conceptually wrong, if someone can point me in te right direcction ill be very grateful!

1-The user access my main page on route:/ receives the corresponding  public html/css /JS  and have the option to a fills a form, and send a post request with that data to route /validation.
2-on the server side i receive the post request, with the data provide by the user, i make some validations on that data

### and here comes the part im very doubtfull

depending on the validation i want to send to the user a response with data containing reasigning values for existing variables inside the public js file sent in first place, (like setting the value of a variable to block, to open a modal, or just adding some innerhtml)
I believe i cannot modified the public js already sent, but i want to know if i can respond with a redirection to route / again, but adding the reasigned variable inside the response.
and is if that the proper way of doing what i im trying to do.

I know i can redirect my user to another totally diferente route, but in principle that is not how i would like it to be.

any help or guiding material about this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want a template engine.